# Allow tsnd compile with errors in a JS file with @ts-check

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am migrating a backend project to use typescript with `tsnd`, I have configured the `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "types": ["node"],
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": []
}
```

That is the script I use to start the project:

`"dev": "tsnd --clear -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts"`

But if I put `// @ts-check` in the top of a `js` file I get the error:

`[ERROR] 16:42:50 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:`

I would like to use `// @ts-check` in the `js` files because it helps me to identify problems, but at the same time I don't want the stop the compilation just because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

in my `tsconfig.json` I can add inside the `compilerOptions`: `"checkJs": true`, then I don't need to add those `// @ts-check` in my `js` files anymore, then to allow the compilation of my project even with those errors in the `js` files, I can add also in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "checkJs": false,
    }
  }
```

Keep in mind that is **OUTSIDE** of the `compilerOptions`.

At the end, this is how my `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "types": ["node"],
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "plugins": [
      // Transform paths in output .js files
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" },

      // Transform paths in output .d.ts files (Include this line if you output declarations files)
      { "transform": "typescript-transform-paths", "afterDeclarations": true }
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "checkJs": false,
    }
  }
}
```